# Angular - how can i refresh the data in reactive way(runtime changed) when multiple component open at same time without reloading the page

Tags: angular, angular6

my scenario is like i have two component which is product component and user component whose url path is like '/product' and '/user' respectively. Both component fetch the data from local storage. both are independent component which means both runs on separate urls. so When i open multiple tab in my browser, in one tab i open product url and in other tab i open user url both at same time. If i make any changes in user or product how can i update the data of another component without reloading the page.

Does it possible to notify seperate component which doesnt have parent child relationship can communicate with each other ?

Comment: use service worker: https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-intro

Comment: i dont understand how does it help to share the data between component at runtime